# ANDROID -insert data into database, report Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, mysql, sql, database

I had been stucked to get the data (contain insert SQL) in assets folder into database. I had tried a lot of changes but my comp report :

```
"Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.restaurant.sesame/com.restaurant.sesame.Food}:   java.lang.NullPointerException"
```

This is my food.txt file content :

```
 INSERT INTO Food (name,detail,price)VALUES ('Cow Rib Steak', '1h 37m Shipping: $11.00', '11.00')
 INSERT INTO Food (name,detail,price)VALUES ('Cow Rib Steak', '1h 37m Shipping: $11.00', '11.00')
 INSERT INTO Food (name,detail,price)VALUES ('Cow Rib Steak', '1h 37m Shipping: $11.00', '11.00')
 INSERT INTO Food (name,detail,price)VALUES ('Cow Rib Steak', '1h 37m Shipping: $11.00', '11.00')
```

I had been struggled for a long time. I had visited a lot of site to research on this.
Can someone suggest a more solid way to help me to solve this error?

```
  public class Restaurant extends Activity {
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_DETAIL = "detail";
public static final String KEY_PRICE = "price";


private static final String DATABASE_NAME ="Restaurantdb";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE ="Food";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;
private final Context ourContext;
private DBHelper ourHelper;

InputStream input;
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
static String value;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
           input = assetManager.open("food.txt");

                  int size = input.available();
                  byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                  input.read(buffer);
                  input.close();

                  // byte buffer into a string
                   value = new String(buffer);


      } catch (IOException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
          }
}

private static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Food (" + KEY_ROWID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    +KEY_NAME+" TEXT NOT NULL, "+KEY_DETAIL+ " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_PRICE+ " DECIMAL (18,2) NOT NULL );"
                );
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Bill ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT NOT NULL,"+
                " price  DECIMAL (18,2) NOT NULL, quantity INTEGER NOT NULL, total DECIMAL (18,2) NOT NULL );"
            );



        db.rawQuery(value, null);

        Log.w("my app", "insert data into NEW DB");
    }
```

Comment: give some more stacktrace to find where the problem is

Comment: stacktrace? Sorry I don't understand.

Comment: i mean your so called "comp report" that is "Unable to start..". Please post the remaining lines so it would be useful to track where the problem is !!

Comment: 04-01 20:45:24.463: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
04-01 20:45:24.463: E/AndroidRuntime(363): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
04-01 20:45:24.463: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
04-01 20:45:24.463: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-01 20:45:24.463: E/AndroidRuntime(363): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

Answer (score 0):

i think you are searching on the wrong tail :)

> Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

so i suggest the problem could be in this activity onCreate()

--- sorry i cant comment your post :/